# What is the meaning of CDECL in this code?

Tags: c, winapi

here I have a code from  the book programming windows fifth edition.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int CDECL MessageBoxPrintf(TCHAR * szCaption, TCHAR * szFormat, ...)
{
    TCHAR szBuffer[1024];
    va_list pArgList;
    // The va_start macro (defined in STDARG.H) is usually equivalent to:
    // pArgList = (char *) &szFormat + sizeof (szFormat) ;
    va_start(pArgList, szFormat);
    // The last argument to wvsprintf points to the arguments
    _vsntprintf(szBuffer, sizeof (szBuffer) / sizeof (TCHAR),
       szFormat, pArgList);
    // The va_end macro just zeroes out pArgList for no good reason
    va_end(pArgList);
    return MessageBox(NULL, szBuffer, szCaption, 0);
}
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    int cxScreen, cyScreen;
    cxScreen = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    cyScreen = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    MessageBoxPrintf(TEXT("ScrnSize"),
        TEXT("The screen is %i pixels wide by %i pixels high."),
        cxScreen, cyScreen);
    return 0;
}
```

what is the meaning of CDECL after int in below code?

> ```
> int CDECL MessageBoxPrintf(TCHAR * szCaption, TCHAR * szFormat, ...)
> ```

Comment: It stands for `C Declaration` and is a calling convention. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: Its  default calling convention for C\C++ programs.You can read about it here [link] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks.aspx)

Comment: @ameyCU: There is no such thing as a default calling convention for C/C++ programs. In fact, neither C nor C++ even mention calling conventions at all. It's an artifact of compiler implementations, and some pick `__cdecl` as their default (Visual Studio for Windows, 32-bit). In 16-bit Windows, the default calling convention was `__stdcall`. For 64-bit Windows, there is only one calling convention. Either way, `CDECL` is not even a calling convention: It's a preprocessor macro.

Comment: @IInspectable Sorry if  I got that wrong but  would you please explain then what the   link explains I provided in my comment.

Comment: @ameyCU: The link documents the `__cdecl` calling convention as implemented by the Microsoft Compiler for 32-bit Intel platforms. Not sure why you are asking this. After all, this is very well explained in the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the windows header files, `CDECL` is defined like this:

```
#define CDECL
```

This seems a little odd. It is a macro that expands to nothing. Used where a calling convention is expected it results in the default calling convention, namely `__cdecl`.

Comment: Doing this *assumes* the default calling convention is `__cdecl`, but some compilers have an option to specify a different default.

Comment: @Remy yes, it does seem pretty odd.

Comment: That's not entirely correct: The quoted line of code is wrapped inside an `#ifndef CDECL` conditional (see *minwindef.h*).

Comment: @IInspectable which I suppose gives users of the header the opportunity to write `#define CDECL __cdecl` before they include the windows headers.